# Props should at least define their types

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, eslint, nuxt.js, storyblok

```
<template>
  <div 
    v-editable="blok" 
    class="util__flex">
    <component 
      v-for="blok in blok.columns" 
      :key="blok._uid" 
      :blok="blok" 
      :is="blok.component"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['blok']
}
</script>
```

Im doing tutorial at Storyblok, and I do get such an error.

https://www.storyblok.com/tp/nuxt-js-multilanguage-website-tutorial#creating-the-homepage-components

> Props should at least define their types  vue/require-prop-types

Comment: See [prop types](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Types) and [prop validation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have probably enabled ESlint on project initialization (see `create-nuxt-app` options), that activated this mandatory rule.

So you have to declare a following type:

- String
- Number
- Boolean
- Array
- Object
- Date
- Function
- Symbol

See Vue.js doc:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Types
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks

For your case:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    blok: Object
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 17):

For current `nuxt` version(v2.8.1), we should set **props** as follows:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    blok: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    }
  }
}
</script>
```